# how to get only last value in a foreach? php

Tags: php, foreach

```
foreach ($data['data'] as $data) { 
 echo $data['title'][0]; 
 //echo '<br />';
}
```

this will print out:

```
melon
apple
... 
banana
pear
```

Now, how to jump all, only get the last value in a foreach? only need `pear`. Thanks.

Comment: Don't use `foreach` at all. Use `$data['data'][last index]`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you only need the last value, then you don't need to loop. You can use [**`end()`**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.end.php):

```
$lastItem = end($data['data']);
echo $lastItem['title'][0];
```

Note that this will set the internal array pointer to the last element. It might be necessary that you call [**`reset($data)`**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.reset.php) afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

End has already been suggested (which I can recommend actually), however if you want to do it with foreach, you could do:

```
foreach ($data['data'] as $data) {
}
echo $data['title'][0]; 
//echo '<br />';
```

but this is really superfluous. You iterate over the array then only to store the last element into `$data`. So if there are no elements in 'data' at all this will fail (as with end, but end will return a false if the array is empty).

So go for:

```
$data=end($data['data']);
```